# conditional expression in derived column

Tags: c#, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I have a problem with this code in the derived column expression :

```
ISNULL( [Lib_Offre]  )  ? (DT_WSTR,7 )'unknown'  :  UPPER( [Lib_Offre]  )
```

It gaves me this error :

`Failed to set property "Expression" on "" Lib_Offre "input column (275)." Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204006 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)`

NB : `Lib_Offre` is a field of data type `DT_WSTR (15)` and what i really want, is to test if this field is null, then put `Unknown` in the target ifnot put that field on capital letters.

Thank you for respending me.

Answer (score 0):

`'unknown'` must be like this
`"unknwon"`
with **quotation marks**

but, hey people, what's wrong with my posts, why all these less point for a reason that I don't know in addition if no Response !!!!